# Expression must have class type when calling length on an array

Tags: c++

I am writing a disjoint set class in C++ and I keep getting this error:

> Expression must have a class type

on this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

My code looks like this:

```
class DisjointSet{
private:
    int *array;
    int size;
public:

    void make_set(int elements){
        array = new int[elements];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
            size += 1;
        }
    }
```

and the error comes up when i try to get `array.length` in the `for` loop. I tried using the `->` operator instead but I'm not sure why this is an issue...

Comment: `array` is a pointer. What magic meaning did you think the member-access (`.`) has for pointers?

Comment: Guessing you come from a java(script)/C# background. Read up on how types work in C++; specifically primitive types in C++ are not objects and do not have properties.

Comment: Use `elements` instead of `array.length`, raw arrays don't support such kind of operations. Or use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Also, unless you've omitted the initialisation of `size`, `size += 1;` will invoke ub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to call a member `.length` on a pointer, but a pointer does not have members or functions.

You should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, which *does* know its size

```
#include <vector>

class DisjointSet{
private:
    std::vector<int> array;
public:
    void make_set(int elements)
    {
        array.clear(); // clear elements
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
        {
            array.push_back(i);
        }
    }
};
```

Now you no longer need to maintain the `size`, because `std::vector` does that for you ([`std::vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)), you no longer need to worry about manually memory management, and you won't have any leaks when you call `make_set` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem in this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

Is in `array.length`. You need to have the empty pair if parenthesis after `length` in `array.length`. Since you do not have that pair of parenthesis, the compiler thinks that `array` is an object of a class with `length` as its member. That is why the compiler gives you:

> Expression must have a class type

**Also**, it is better to use the variable `elements` in the comparison with counter `i` instead of `array.length()`.

Therefore, a better solution would be to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
```

---

**EDIT**: Just some advice, it is alsays a better idea to use the `std::vector` library instead of pointers. It makes your life a whole lot easier.

Also, you have forgotten to initialize the field `size` of your class `DisjointSet`. By incrementing `size` in your for-loop, you are causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: "`Is in array.length. length() is a function`". `array` is just an `int*`, it doesn't have any members.